# IF and IFS not working properly

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, concatenate

I am trying to locate data present in different sheets. I have tried using `IF` and `IFS`.
Below are the formulas I have used. For `IF`, I get `NOT IN USE` even when I know there should be one of the sheets and I get `NA` for `IFS` except 2 cell which gives the correct answer.
What am I doing wrong or is there any other way for it.

```
=IFS(B2=Casula!$A:$A,"CASULA",B2=Miranda!$A:$A,"MIRANDA",B2=Parramatta!$A:$A,"PARRA",B2=Leichhardt!$A:$A,"LEICHHARDT",B2=Penrith!$A:$A,"PENRITH",B2=Bradbury!$A:$A,"BRADBURY",B2=Revesby!A:A,"REVESBY",B2=Darlinghurst!$A:$A,"DARLING",B2=StMarys!A:A,"STMARYS",B2=SurryHills!$A:$A,"SURRY")
```

---

```
=IF(B2=Casula!$A:$A,"Casula",IF(B2=Miranda!$A:$A,"Miranda",IF(B2=Parramatta!$A:$A,"Parra",IF(B2=Leichhardt!$A:$A,"Leich","NOT IN USE"))))
```

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pBUfHQqgkN5QDPU5JIuDsJH4UqmCZDM5IC-rsAoSWWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This question was bumped by Community user. While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, the question should be self-contained. Please include all the relevant details in the question body. In this case, describe the relevant spreadsheet parts, including the spreadsheet locale (country), and add a sample both for formula input as for the expected results.

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Casula!A:A)),       "Casula",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Miranda!A:A)),      "Miranda",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Parramatta!A:A)),   "Parra",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Leichhardt!A:A)),   "Leich",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Penrith!A:A)),      "Penrith",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Bradbury!A:A)),     "Bradbury",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Revesby!A:A)),      "Revesby",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Darlinghurst!A:A)), "Darling",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, StMarys!A:A)),      "Marys",
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SurryHills!A:A)),   "SurryHills",
 "NOT IN USE")))))))))), ))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10nKxs3r7OzCxS9pVMxdc0iPnoYPPX6ir-4ebmpDmWNQ/copy)